# jQuery script setting div height seems to run only once then stops

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have four divs each with the same ID but different class.

```
<div id="inner" class="1"></div>
<div id="inner" class="2"></div>
<div id="inner" class="3"></div>
<div id="inner" class="4"></div>
```

I then have a jQuery script setting the height of the divs to be the height of the window (plus a little bit)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var h = $(window).height();
$('#inner') .css({'height': h+100});
```

However this is only working for Div1, the script seems to stop working for the next 3 divs. Is there a way to keep it running for all 4 divs?

Many Thanks

*quick edit* im obviously new at this and just needed a quick hand, so thank you to the people that gave the time to give me an answer i can work with, and my sincere apologies to the person that negatively voted the question, if it was a burden to you to read, you could have just not read it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ID's must be unique, make their ID's unique or else calling $("#inner") will only return the first div.

HTML:

```
<div class="inner 1"></div>
<div class="inner 2"></div>
<div class="inner 3"></div>
<div class="inner 4"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var h = $(window).height();
$('.inner') .css({'height': h+100});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
<div id="one" class="inner"></div>
<div id="two" class="inner"></div>
<div id="three" class="inner"></div>
<div id="four" class="inner"></div>

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var h = $(window).height();
    $('.inner').css({'height': h+100});
```

IDs must be unique.

Comment: @Rene According to the html5 spec they are allowed to be numeric!

Answer (score 0):

Your id tags are not semantic.  Only one unique ID tag should exist on one page.  You need to add a similar class.

```
<div id="inner" class="1 inners"></div>
<div id="inner2" class="2 inners"></div>
<div id="inner3" class="3 inners"></div>
<div id="inner4" class="4 inners"></div>

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   var h = $(window).height();
   $('.inners') .css({'height': h+100});
}
```